# Links don't work in Firefox

Tags: html, xhtml, css

I have no idea what is wrong.  No links (Navigation or image links) work in Firefox but work perfect in IE and Chrome

http://graves-incorporated.com/test_sites/solera_new/index.html

Please help me out

-Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check element img#rightAligned, it over all your menu links.
try  #layout_style_links {z-index:9999999;} or bigger then current your img#rightAligned z-index

Comment: Your a life saver!! thank you! I thought it had something to do with the z-index

Comment: This worked for the navigation menu, but all the other links and scroll features still don't work...

Answer (score 2):

I don't have Firefox on my laptop unfortunately, but this problem is often due to another element sitting on top of the links. Usually this is caused by a layout element such as a table or div.

Do you have Firebug or similar installed? There are a few developer tools out there that give you a coloured outline of your elements as you select them. It might help you to identify if you have an element sitting on top the links.

Comment: I am working in dreamweaver, is there any option in there to do that?

Comment: I've never really used Dreamweaver unfortunately. Firebug is a free plugin for Firefox. You should check that out [http://getfirebug.com/](http://getfirebug.com/). I used Chrome's developer tools to take a look and it seems okay in there, but apparently Firefox is rendering the page differently.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `td` with absolute positioning (!?) that seems to cover the entire page. Don't use absolute positioning on a `td` element, that's just wrong.

Or even better, don't use tables for layout at all. This isn't the 90s anymore.

Comment: Yes @Dan, it is affecting the links. Get rid of the tables.

Comment: I don't have the time or know how to do that.  Can I just change the positioning or something?

Comment: @Dan: Nope, you'll have to get rid of the tables.

Comment: I would have to redo the whole site!  It needs to go Live tomorrow. I'm screwed.

I thought it maybe had something to do with a few elements I had to adjust the z index

Comment: Do you have any suggestions how I could change that element? The troubled td is for the floating red (also transparent) link in the top right hand corner, Special Events.

I wasn't sure how to pull this off, and took the advice of someone from this site.  How else could I float that image there?

Comment: I didn't know how to do it because like I said it is transparent and slightly overlapping the div below...

Answer (score 1):

This activated the links for me in FF:

```
td.imageholder {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 9999999;
}
```

Comment: What I did to fix this was lowered the z-index of td.imageholder and increased #layout_style_links z-index....but would your option be better?

Comment: my option will hide the offending element, which isn't ideal, but maybe on a tight deadline would be better than nothing. No, go with the option that works right now and address the larger issues at hand as you are able.